# is it possible to parse xml from a different origin in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, xml-parsing

i've been facing problem with xml parsing in chrome.

so i've posted a question regarding that and i came to know about "[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)".

so now i'm here to ask if there is any other possible way so that we can parse xml from a different origin which would work on chrome or safari....?

i came to know about webservices but i have no idea how to write or deal with them ...

please suggest me if there is any other way that can parse my xml from different origin and also some knowledge on how to handle webservices will help . . . . . . .

Thank you............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to use YQL to accomplish this.

Check out http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax for more info

Answer (score 0):

the common way to do cross domain XHR is with a "proxy" script: if you want to access http://other.domain.com/moo.xml you might send an XHR request to /proxy.php?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fother.domain.com%2Fmoo.xml which would then decode the uri GET parameter, and do a curl request to the provided URI, and output the results.

Obviously this could be achieved using many other server-side languages, not just PHP.